# Msbuild : how to create Virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, msbuild

I'm new to MSBuild. I need to create a virtual directory in IIS BUT i dont know how to dont that i tried some tutorials but they are so vague so please guide me my currecnt code is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" >
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Resource >D:\test_2\Tony_Mail\Tony_Mail\Tony_Mail.csproj</Resource>
    <OutputDir>D:\test_2\Tony_Mail\Tony_Mail\Build</OutputDir>
    <clean>D:\test_2\Tony_Mail\Tony_Mail\Build\bin\*.pdb</clean>

  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="D:\test_2\Tony_Mail\Tony_Mail\Tony_Mail.csproj"></MSBuild>
    <CallTarget Targets="Publish"></CallTarget>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Publish">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(Resource)" Targets="ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication" Properties="WebProjectOutputDir=S(OutputDir);OutDir=$(MSBuildProjectsDirectory)\Bin\"></MSBuild>
    <CallTarget Targets="Clean"></CallTarget>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Clean">
    <Delete Files="$(clean)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: You can use task form MSBuildExtensionPack to do these tasks.

Comment: but how I'm not familiar with this  can you give me an example

Comment: They have nice examples in the docs (CHM file), use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the following code

```
<WebDirectoryCreate VirtualDirectoryName="MyVirDir"
     VirtualDirectoryPhysicalPath="C:\Inetpub\MyWebDir" />
```

and also add the delete code before the create otherwise it will cause error for that use the following code

```
<WebDirectoryDelete VirtualDirectoryName="MyVirDir" />
```

so the full code block will be like this

```
<Target Name="VirtualDirectory">
    <WebDirectoryDelete VirtualDirectoryName="MyVirDir" />
    <WebDirectoryCreate VirtualDirectoryName="MyVirDir"
        VirtualDirectoryPhysicalPath="C:\Inetpub\MyWebDir" />
</Target>
```